# SQL subtotaling

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a SQL Server 2008 query which will output data into subtotaled columns. My SQL skills are pretty poor still, so I could really use some help.

I have two tables, A and B.

```
A.user (unique) 
A.answer  <- can only be one of two answers, 'Answer1' or 'Answer2' 
B.user (unique) 
B.zip
```

What I am trying to do is write a SQL statement that generates a four column output that summarizes answer by zip. Like this:

```
Zip    Answer1    Answer2   Total
----------------------------------
12345     25        22        47
23456     7          0         7
45678     0         15        15
```

Any sage advice?

Thanks!

-tony

Comment: You have two tables, but how are they related to each other?

Comment: inner join on A.user = B.user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is what you need:

```
SELECT B.Zip 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN answer='Answer1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Answer1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN answer='Answer2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS Answer2
     , COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.[user] = B.[user]
GROUP BY B.Zip
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60916/2/0